# Make Elements On A Visual Basic Form Draggable

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to make a Visual Basic Form that has a specified set of elements that can be dragged to another location on the form by the user. How can I do this? I have looked on Google, and done some searching on StackOverflow, but I have found absolutely nothing.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an article on this topic long time back, which might be of help to you.

[Drag & Drop Files into Your Form or Control](http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2010/03/04/drag-drop-files-into-your-form-or-control/)

In that example I showed how to drag files into your form or control. Your requirements are slightly different, but the basic idea about dragging remains the same.

Have a look at this example which demonstrates how you can drag one control into another on your form. 
For this example, put two listboxes on your form - `ListBox1` and `ListBox2`, and add the following code:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.AllowDrop = True
    ListBox2.AllowDrop = True

    ListBox1.Items.Add("Test Item 1")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Test Item 2")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Test Item 3")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Test Item 4")

    ListBox2.Items.Add("Test Item 5")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("Test Item 6")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("Test Item 7")
    ListBox2.Items.Add("Test Item 8")

End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxes_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown, ListBox2.MouseDown
    Dim lb As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)
    lb.DoDragDrop(lb, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxes_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DragEnter, ListBox2.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxes_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DragDrop, ListBox2.DragDrop
    If TypeOf sender Is ListBox Then
        Dim lb As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)
        Dim srcLb As ListBox = e.Data.GetData(GetType(ListBox))
        If lb IsNot srcLb Then
            lb.Items.Add(srcLb.SelectedItem.ToString)
            srcLb.Items.Remove(srcLb.SelectedItem)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now drag items from one listbox into the other, and vice-versa and see the effect.

EDIT:

**Moving Controls on the Form**

(added after OP's clarification in comments)

Moving controls on the form is something entirely different than the dragging thing I showed above. You can simply capture the MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp events to do this.

Here is an example. Put a lot of controls on your form, and add the following code:

```
Private Moving As Boolean
Private Sub Controls_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(ctl.Location + New Point(ctl.Width \ 2, ctl.Height \ 2))
    Moving = True
End Sub

Private Sub Controls_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    If Moving Then
        Dim ctl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
        ctl.Location = PointToClient(Cursor.Position - New Point(ctl.Width \ 2, ctl.Height \ 2))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Controls_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    Moving = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
        ctl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll
        AddHandler ctl.MouseDown, AddressOf Controls_MouseDown
        AddHandler ctl.MouseUp, AddressOf Controls_MouseUp
        AddHandler ctl.MouseMove, AddressOf Controls_MouseMove
    Next
End Sub
```

Run the application and drag controls here and there on the form.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use this on buttons and such? That is what I had in mind when I mentioned moving objects.

Comment: What I showed above is using the listboxes. It was just for an example. You can use any other control too. Just go thru the `ListBoxes_DragDrop` method and observe that you have the reference of the object you were dragging. Similarly if you drag a `Button` control you will get the reference of that button and you can do whatever you want to do with it. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to move data from one control to another or just want to shift their physical positions on the form?

Comment: I am trying to shift a form elements physical location on the form.

Comment: It is an entirely different thing. I have edited the post above and added the code showing how to move controls physically here and there on the form. :)